# No axis named 1 for object type Series

Tags: python

I'm using df.iloc[i] to assign (ori + gap) on each row of the dataframe. But I got 'No axis named 1 for object type Series' error. And I don't understand why.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('异常销量监控_0127_to Xiaolei Eagle send.csv',low_memory=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv('test0412.csv',dtype = {'Actual':float})
gap = 0
for i in range(len(df2)):
  ym = df2['YM'].iloc[i]
  kcode = df2['REPKCode'].iloc[i]
  fn = df2['FamilyNameE'].iloc[i]
  ori = float(df2['Actual'].iloc[i])
  filt = (df1['YM'] == ym )& (df1['REPKCode'] == kcode) & (df1['FamilyNameE'] == fn))
  gap = df1[filt]['Actual']
  df2['Actual'].iloc[i] = (ori + gap)
df2.to_csv('after.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in the following line

```
 filt = (df1['YM'] == ym )& (df1['REPKCode'] == kcode) & (df1['FamilyNameE'] == fn))
 gap = df1[filt]['Actual']
```

the value of **filt** will be either 1 or 0 because you are checking multiple conditions

```
 (df1['YM'] == ym )& (df1['REPKCode'] == kcode) & (df1['FamilyNameE'] == fn))
```

and if the above condition is true , **filt** will be assigned 1 otherwise 0.

So your condition was true and filt == 1

Now in the following line

```
 gap = df1[filt]['Actual']
```

you are actually doing this

```
 gap = df1[1]['Actual']
```

Its trying to find the column '1' in df1 dataframe and because there is no column as '1' thats why its giving you error.

---

**EDIT**

Reply to your comment - ***How can I get the 'Actual' value with 'YM','REPKCode','FamilyNameE' match in df1?***

for that you need to write below lines

```
gap =  df1[ df1['YM'] == ym ][ df1['REPKCode'] == kcode][ df1['FamilyNameE'] == fn]['Actual']
```

and remove below lines

```
 filt = (df1['YM'] == ym )& (df1['REPKCode'] == kcode) & (df1['FamilyNameE'] == fn))
 gap = df1[filt]['Actual']
```

Comment: So in your dataframe df1 do you have any column named as "1" ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I changed the gap to: "gap = df1[(df1['YM'] == ym) & (df1['REPKCode']== kcode) & (df1['FamilyNameE'] == fn)]['Actual']" but it seems still doesn't work.

Comment: How can I get the 'Actual' value with 'YM','REPKCode','FamilyNameE' match in df1?

Comment: @JadeZhang Yes I have edited my answer, you can see the solution there...hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is,
`df2["YM"].iloc[i]` 
because when you are typed `df2["YM"]` it returns `YM` column from the dataframe `df2`.
So, that means you are trying to get a column from the column by typing `df2["YM"].iloc[i]`.
Try, `df2.iloc[i]`

Comment: And one other thing, it is good to use `range(df.shape[0])` instead of `range(len(df2)`. because, `df2` is a 2D array.

Comment: Thanks for replying I changed the code to df2.iloc[i]. But now I got :
"df2.iloc[i]['Actual'] = (ori + gap)
<ipython-input-175-0b5e57744511>:9: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame" this error.